# What solutions exist for lightweight version control of an entire system image?

Tags: linux, git, bash, docker, embedded

Say you're building a safety-critical software appliance to run on a capable embedded system like the [NVIDIA Jetson TK1](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/develop/hardware). The main application will run in Linux, and that is managed with Git. But you also want to have tight control over the entire system state - changes to the network settings, startup, shared libraries, etc. What's more, you want to be able to do development against this system image on a desktop computer running a different OS.

There is a default system image that will be flashed onto the board. You could make changes, save off the whole image, and then re-flash it, but this can take >30 minutes. Not a good workflow.

You could write a bash script that reaches out into the surrounding filesystem and makes the required changes during installation, and then keep that script controlled in Git. But this can be a somewhat brittle and laborious way to do things since it's imperative. To prove that it works, you have to revert the system to its assumed default state and then re-install. If the system secretly has some differences from that assumed state, the installation could fail.

You could virtualize the environment (does this exist for this hardware though?). Does this make it harder to take advantage of the board-specific hardware, like the Jetson's GPU?

Isn't there a better, more declarative way to solve this? Is there a system out there that just lets me press "save" on the way I have the system setup, commit it, and then pull it onto a different platform without waiting for a 30 minute flash?

Comment: For an embedded system you tend to create the whole distro. So you version the parts you use to make that distro, along with the default configs. This can either be done by hand, or using something like the Yocto project - https://www.yoctoproject.org/

Comment: You appear to be asking "how do I get a consistent filesystem/etc. state on a machine without flashing it to ensure consistency". Configuration management tools (puppet, chef, ansible, salt, etc.) can handle some of this in a declarative way but that won't stop unmanaged details from skewing.

Comment: Satellite server may somewhat answer a few of your questions. Package all your different updates and then you can customize the builds based on what versions of what packages you want to use and store those into "profiles". Cobbler to reinstall. From satellite you can pull entire package lists and system information as well.

Comment: **Spacewalk** is the opensource version. From there website "
◾Inventory your systems (hardware and software information)
◾Install and update software on your systems
◾Collect and distribute your custom software packages into manageable groups
◾Provision (kickstart) your systems
◾Manage and deploy configuration files to your systems
◾Provision and start/stop/configure virtual guests
◾Distribute content across multiple geographical sites in an efficient manner."

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback.

Comment: @Joe: I've seen yocto before, it seems like a good option for fully creating a perfectly tailored, unique distribution just for your embedded use case. I was hoping to find something that didn't require the legwork of creating something extremely bespoke. While I hope to track a "large" number of changes to the default image, the amount of state contained in those changes is still small compared to the information required to configure the entire operating system. Configuring the whole distro feels like overkill, which I had imagined was a common use case.

Comment: @Etan: Thanks for the input. My impression of those tools had always been that they were specifically designed for an enterprise to to ensure consistency across servers, and therefore focused on the mechanics of how one communicates and syncs that state, quietly making a lot of implicit assumptions that the underlying devices looked and quacked like web servers. Wouldn't those tools be unwieldy for essentially just trying to wrap up the OS's state into a config file? I'd feel like I'm solving a decades-old problem with tools that are 2 years old, which always makes me wary.

Comment: None of those tools have anything to do with web servers that I'm aware of. And you are exactly trying to have consistent configuration regardless of starting point which is what they do as far as I understand them (at least for the things they cover). I used to work with people who had CFengine scripts for this sort of thing. People have used revision control for this as well. People have used various other script-based/manual tools for this over the years too. I don't know a long-standing tool that does this as there wasn't the same "general" need for it (but I just play a sysadmin on tv).

Comment: Thanks Etan, I'm a neophyte in this arena so the context is all very helpful.